# accessing a certain json object

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop

So i been busting my head trying to access a certain a element through a for loop in JS, i am drawing a blank.  I have JSON objects with 15 elements (example of one below.  I am trying to access the "phones".phone_number element but getting undefined.  Below is also my for loop.

right now i am just console logging all the elements.   the first two, .name and address come back find but its the phones that is not coming back with the results.

```
for(var i=0; i < json.business.length; i++ ){

  console.log(json.business[i].name);
  console.log(json.business[i].found_at_address.street_line_1);
  console.log(json.business[i].phones[i].phone_number);

}


{
    "count_business": 15,
    "business": [
        {
            "id": "Business.7146cd10-735f-4710-b145-93b97fe45e07",
            "name": "Grace Christian Fellowship",
            "industry": [
                "Religious, Grantmaking, Civic, Professional, and Similar Organizations"
            ],
            "found_at_address": {
                "id": "Location.5c80fbd1-5e5a-4356-9725-5492e3942091",
                "location_type": "Address",
                "street_line_1": "210 2nd St",
                "street_line_2": null,
                "city": "Mounds",
                "postal_code": "62964",
                "zip4": "1144",
                "state_code": "IL",
                "country_code": "US",
                "lat_long": {
                    "latitude": 37.113098,
                    "longitude": -89.200842,
                    "accuracy": "RoofTop"
                },
                "is_active": true,
                "delivery_point": "POBoxThrowback",
                "link_to_business_start_date": "2016-11-19",
                "link_to_business_end_date": null
            },
            "current_addresses": [
                {
                    "id": "Location.5c80fbd1-5e5a-4356-9725-5492e3942091",
                    "location_type": "Address",
                    "street_line_1": "210 2nd St",
                    "street_line_2": null,
                    "city": "Mounds",
                    "postal_code": "62964",
                    "zip4": "1144",
                    "state_code": "IL",
                    "country_code": "US",
                    "lat_long": {
                        "latitude": 37.113098,
                        "longitude": -89.200842,
                        "accuracy": "RoofTop"
                    },
                    "is_active": true,
                    "delivery_point": "POBoxThrowback",
                    "link_to_business_start_date": "2016-11-19"
                }
            ],
            "historical_addresses": [],
            "phones": [
                {
                    "id": "Phone.46c16fef-a2e1-4b08-cfe3-bc7128b6e19a",
                    "phone_number": "+16187459424",
                    "line_type": "Landline"
                }
            ],
            "associated_people": [],
            "associated_businesses": [
                {
                    "id": "Business.e43f1c0d-ecec-42da-ad1c-76badfdf2dcf",
                    "name": "Usda Rural Development",
                    "industry": [
                        "Administration of Housing Programs, Urban Planning, and Community Development"
                    ],
                    "relation": "Household"
                }
            ]
        },
```

Comment: you're using i twice, which doesn't make sense. add a second loop.

Comment: what do you mean? I only have one loop.  can you elaborate please?

Comment: In this case, it's `phones[0]` instead of `phones[i]`, but asuming phones is an array for a reason, you'd need to loop through phones and grab the phone number(s) you want.

Comment: @Chris since `phones` only has one value, don't access it using `phones[i]`. Use `phones[0]` and see if it works

Comment: you need two loops. `console.log(json.business[i].phones[i].phone_number);`

The first loop is for businiess and the second is for phones

Comment: when i run the 2nd loop i get an error saying Error:  Cannot read property 'phone_number' of undefined.

for(var i=0; i < json.business.length; i++ ){
  
 console.log(json.business[i].phones[i].phone_number);
}

Comment: @AniketG if i modified the code to that, it does bring the result back for the first element only.   but repeats the same number over all the elements.   There is 15.  Id like to get the "phones".phone_number element for all 15 through a loop.

Comment: Make another for loop and try it. `for (var x = 0; x < json.business[i]phones.length; x++) {}`. When accessing `phone_number`, do `json.business[i].phones[x].phone_number`

Comment: @AniketG another separate loop or the loop inside my loop?

Comment: @Chris right after the line that says: `console.log(json.business[i].found_at_address.street_line_1);`

Comment: @AniketG yes!, this worked, thank you so much.

Comment: @Chris I'll add it into an answer for you with a bit of explanation.

Comment: @Chris in my answer, I suggested an alternate solution. Look at that solution, and if I were you, I'd use it. It's much simpler

Comment: @AniketG i really like this, however, i am getting  a Erro: missing ) after argument list.

Comment: @Chris Right so sorry. I had a syntax error in my code. That error means that there's a mising `)` somewhere. I fixed my code below. P.S. Comment on my answer for these kind of quesitons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a separate loop when looping through the `phones` array. Since `json.business.length` is 15, `i` will go all the way up to 14. However, `phones.length` is only 1, so `phones[14]` would throw an error.

Use the code below:

```
for(var i=0; i < json.business.length; i++ ){
    console.log(json.business[i].name);
    console.log(json.business[i].found_at_address.street_line_1);

    for (var x = 0; x < json.business[i].phones.length; x++) {
        console.log(json.business[i].phones[x].phone_number);
    }
}
```

**Note:** A better way to do this would be to use a [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop. This basically loops through the whole array and is much easier than a `for` loop.

```
json.business.forEach(business => {
    console.log(business.name);
    console.log(business.found_at_address.street_line_1);

    business.forEach(phones => {
        console.log(phones.phone_number);
    }
})
```

A [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop basically does what a `for` loop does, but in this case, `business` would be `json.business[i]`